# Why is the GPS Chip Not detected on ARCHOS Alba 4?

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, gps, gps-tracking, archos-gen8

I am using Android Nougat, but there are no options for GPS in the locations menus (just battery saving >> wifi, bluetooth and cellular network only)

Other GPS apps do not even detect the chip in the first place... why?

Comment: Does the phone run an original ROM from the manufacturer or a custom ROM?

Comment: Are you sure that tablet has GPS at all? Does it say so in the specs? If it has no GPS chip, it obviously cannot be detected.

Comment: The phone has the original ROM, and it definitely does have a GPS chip (its a phone, not a tablet)

Comment: Starting in Android 7.0, Location Access menus have migrated under the Security Settings menus.  The exact menu area could be different depending on OEMs, however.

Comment: There is no location setting in the security menu....